# Keeping two colours on simultaneously using maphilight jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins

I am currently using David Lynch's  maphighlight jquery plugin.

link - http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

I would like to have two different colours on simultaneously on an image map , with the alwaysOn feature set to true.

I have attached my code snippet below. **Its key features are** :

1)The default highlight on hover is green and when you double click on the image, the colour changes to red.

2) Once you have chosen your colour, you left click,  hold the mousedown and drag through multiple image areas to highlight them.

3) You can also click on already highlighted areas to remove the highlight.

**The one additional feature that I badly need is:** After you click and drag and highlight a number of areas . When I double click (which changes the highlight hover colour), I would like the already highlighted areas to remain as they are and not change colour.

The current problem is when I double click all the highlighted areas change colour.

Any help regarding this would be very much appreciated!

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.js">
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
var  click_flag = 1;  //changes value each time a click is made
var  loop_control = 1; // is a flag to run only one click loop at a time
var down = false;

// setting mouse hover default colours
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.mapHighLight').maphilight({ 
  fillColor: '00ff00', strokeColor:'000000'
 });

// function to change colour 
 $('area').dblclick(function(e){  
  if(click_flag == 1 && loop_control == 1){
   $('.mapHighLight').maphilight({ 
   fillColor: 'ff0000', strokeColor:'000000' // red
   }); 
  click_flag = 0;
  //alert("1st loop "+ ":click_flag = "+click_flag+" and loop_control = "+loop_control);
  }
 }); 
 
 
 $('area').dblclick(function(e){
  if(click_flag == 0 && loop_control == 0){
   $('.mapHighLight').maphilight({ 
   fillColor: '00ff00', strokeColor:'000000' //green
   });
  click_flag = 1;
  //alert("2nd loop "+ ":click_flag = "+click_flag+" and loop_control = "+loop_control);
  }
 });
 
// this section is set the correct flag values at the right time.    
 function status_change(){     
  if(click_flag == 1){loop_control = 1};   
  if(click_flag == 0){loop_control = 0};
  //alert("3rd loop "+ ":click_flag = "+click_flag+" and loop_control = "+loop_control) 
 }


// the delay is to make this code run in the end, to ensure proper change of values.  
 $('area').dblclick(function(e){ 
  setTimeout(status_change,500); 
 });          
 
 
// this function is for mouse hold    
   $('area').bind({     
  mousedown : function(e){
   down = true;
  },
  mousemove : function(e){
   if(down){
    var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
    data.alwaysOn = true;
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
   }
  },
  mouseup : function(e){
   down = false;
  }
 });


//This block is to turn off "alwaysOn" feature of maphilight plugin 
 $("area").click(function(e){          
  var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
  data.alwaysOn = false;//!data.alwaysOn;
  $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
 });
}); 
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class = "mapHighLight "  src = "http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/dermatome_torso1.png" alt = "dermatomeUpperbodyFront" usemap = "#upper1">
<map class = "dMap1" name = "upper1">
<area id = "t1R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="77,95,53,59,63,43,75,34,93,19,110,11,126,4,141,1,158,2,173,3,191,4,205,5,220,6,236,6,255,7,274,8,297,8,312,10,328,9,340,8,341,16,340,27,340,38,341,52,320,52,297,52,278,51,262,50,244,48,223,47,198,46,177,46,154,48,133,54,112,61,94,73" />
<area id = "t1L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,10,343,52,373,50,391,50,408,49,426,50,441,50,458,51,474,52,486,56,498,62,510,68,521,82,526,93,527,96,531,90,534,80,550,35,537,23,522,17,505,10,481,5,438,6,412,9,381,9,354,10" />
<area id = "t2R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="90,121,77,95,86,82,104,69,119,60,136,53,158,48,176,46,195,45,221,46,241,48,265,50,283,51,305,52,329,53,341,52,342,95,319,95,288,93,267,92,240,92,212,91,189,91,162,92,142,96,119,103"/>
<area id = "t2L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,52,344,94,393,95,404,95,426,94,442,94,461,95,474,97,492,101,502,107,512,115,526,96,517,78,505,67,490,58,466,52,433,51,404,51,376,51,353,51" />
<area id = "t3R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="87,144,85,127,105,112,120,104,141,98,162,93,190,91,211,90,238,92,266,92,286,94,317,96,331,95,342,94,343,138,316,140,282,139,250,136,220,133,189,132,162,131,139,132,113,136" />
<area id = "t3L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,95,342,139,365,138,390,136,416,135,440,134,460,132,480,131,500,135,516,142,516,124,509,114,491,102,467,96,430,95,394,96,362,95" />
<area id = "t4R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,139,341,190,321,190,295,192,268,192,244,192,221,191,184,190,170,188,153,187,136,184,110,179,98,174,88,171,85,145,100,139,120,134,140,132,160,130,182,132,206,133,237,135,256,137,275,139,296,140,318,140"/>
<area id = "t4L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,139,342,190,364,192,396,194,417,192,445,190,466,183,481,179,496,174,505,168,515,162,515,140,498,134,473,131,448,134,420,136,393,136,368,139,349,139" />
<area id = "t5R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,191,342,239,326,237,312,235,285,237,261,240,234,239,210,239,189,237,169,236,149,233,129,229,113,225,100,219,90,213,88,171,98,176,110,181,129,185,149,188,172,191,196,192,218,192,237,193,262,193,287,193,314,192,325,192" />
<area id = "t5L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,191,342,239,364,241,393,240,417,240,443,235,465,231,480,226,494,220,504,216,512,208,514,207,513,163,504,170,487,179,465,185,439,192,417,193,400,195,364,193" />
<area id = "t6R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,239,342,280,318,283,294,283,272,283,252,280,226,280,205,278,182,276,161,273,146,267,132,261,117,254,105,247,94,240,93,213,110,223,128,230,152,233,172,235,197,236,229,239,254,239,281,238,304,235,317,235,331,238" />
<area id = "t6L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,239,343,283,368,282,392,281,416,279,436,275,455,268,472,261,486,253,496,248,505,240,512,236,515,208,501,217,486,224,458,233,432,237,402,240,372,241,353,240" />
<area id = "t7R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,283,343,336,322,336,288,333,262,332,231,328,209,323,190,320,172,315,152,310,136,305,120,299,108,289,102,287,96,240,108,249,125,259,144,267,166,274,188,279,211,280,242,282,269,283,294,284,317,284" />
<area id = "t7L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,282,344,334,373,331,406,327,428,322,451,314,472,307,490,296,501,287,506,279,513,234,505,240,489,250,473,259,449,268,428,275,418,277,389,280,357,281" />
<area id = "t8R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,335,342,374,319,375,298,377,276,377,248,373,224,368,204,362,179,355,158,348,140,342,128,336,117,330,105,288,116,295,128,303,143,307,162,312,181,318,200,322,224,326,249,331,273,332,298,334,325,335" />
<area id = "t8L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,335,342,374,354,374,374,372,392,370,408,365,424,360,438,354,449,348,462,341,474,336,486,328,498,319,502,303,505,290,505,283,498,290,488,298,472,307,455,311,437,317,418,322,396,326,377,331" />
<area id = "t9R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="336,374,337,424,329,423,320,419,310,420,299,422,286,423,277,423,261,418,246,412,234,403,217,394,201,388,185,382,169,378,156,374,140,368,131,362,122,358,117,329,125,334,133,339,146,344,158,348,175,354,188,358,204,363,218,366,232,370,251,374,265,375,282,376,296,376,314,376" />
<area id = "t9L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="336,376,337,424,358,423,372,419,385,412,406,403,418,395,430,389,445,381,462,373,474,367,487,358,493,352,499,319,490,327,478,334,464,343,451,349,433,357,417,363,396,369,366,375,345,376" />
<area id = "t10R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="330,424,331,482,310,482,296,481,274,477,254,469,238,460,227,449,206,435,195,427,177,417,164,412,150,405,138,398,128,393,122,359,132,365,148,372,162,377,178,383,195,389,212,395,228,401,244,411,260,418,272,423,287,424,303,423,315,420,324,422" />
<area id = "t10L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="330,424,333,481,354,479,368,476,380,469,392,463,401,453,414,440,423,429,437,419,449,410,463,402,476,393,488,387,493,351,486,359,474,367,459,375,440,384,428,391,414,399,402,405,385,414,368,419,351,424" />
<area id = "t11R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="316,481,317,545,298,546,279,544,264,540,250,533,235,525,221,511,212,498,200,480,188,467,173,454,160,444,146,437,134,429,125,420,127,391,141,401,157,409,177,417,193,426,212,439,233,456,246,467,265,473,282,479,301,482" />
<area id = "t11L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="317,482,317,545,340,542,359,536,376,529,392,518,406,506,418,487,429,473,442,458,455,443,466,435,483,426,492,424,489,387,474,394,459,403,443,412,433,420,422,430,410,442,400,452,386,466,368,475,342,481" />
<area id = "t12R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="300,547,301,596,278,596,262,593,247,588,234,580,228,568,221,557,210,536,200,521,187,507,176,497,160,481,147,475,133,464,126,460,122,420,134,429,146,436,159,444,177,457,193,473,206,489,218,509,235,525,250,535,270,542" />
<area id = "t12L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="300,547,302,597,329,595,347,594,367,586,382,573,394,553,406,533,419,515,432,497,448,482,464,469,480,460,488,457,492,424,477,429,462,438,447,451,436,464,424,480,413,495,400,511,377,527,358,537,321,545" />
</map>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to achieve the original features I wanted but I did find an alternate solution using maphilight . I used the "hover" and "click & drag" events  to be green in colour. After that I set the "click" event  to turn clicked areas red. This way I was able to have two colours on at the same time with no mapped area having a fixed colour setting.

I have attached the code snippet along with this answer. Just in case someone might find it useful.

Please note that this feature has only been tested with jquery 1.11.1 or 1.11.2 version

```js
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/jquery.maphilight.js">
        </script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var  click_flag = 1;  //changes value each time a click is made
            var  loop_control = 1; // is a flag to run only one click loop at a time
            var down = false;

// setting mouse hover default colours
            $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.mapHighLight').maphilight({ 
      fillColor: '00ff00', strokeColor:'000000'
     });

// this function is for mouse hold    
            $('area').bind({     
         mousedown : function(){
      down = true;
  },
  mousemove : function(){
      if(down){
          var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
   data.alwaysOn = true;
   data.fillColor = '00ff00';
   $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
   $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('fillColor.maphilight');
   }
  },
  mouseup : function(){
      down = false;
  }
     });


//This block is to turn off "alwaysOn" feature of maphilight plugin 
     $("area").click(function(){          
         var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
  data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
  data.fillColor = 'ff0000';
  $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
  $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('fillColor.maphilight');
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>  
        <img class = "spot mapHighLight "  src = "http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/dermatome_torso1.png" alt = "dermatomeUpperbodyFront" usemap = "#upper1">
            <map class = "dMap1" name = "upper1">
                <area id = "t1R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="77,95,53,59,63,43,75,34,93,19,110,11,126,4,141,1,158,2,173,3,191,4,205,5,220,6,236,6,255,7,274,8,297,8,312,10,328,9,340,8,341,16,340,27,340,38,341,52,320,52,297,52,278,51,262,50,244,48,223,47,198,46,177,46,154,48,133,54,112,61,94,73" />
                <area id = "t1L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,10,343,52,373,50,391,50,408,49,426,50,441,50,458,51,474,52,486,56,498,62,510,68,521,82,526,93,527,96,531,90,534,80,550,35,537,23,522,17,505,10,481,5,438,6,412,9,381,9,354,10" />
                <area id = "t2R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="90,121,77,95,86,82,104,69,119,60,136,53,158,48,176,46,195,45,221,46,241,48,265,50,283,51,305,52,329,53,341,52,342,95,319,95,288,93,267,92,240,92,212,91,189,91,162,92,142,96,119,103"/>
                <area id = "t2L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,52,344,94,393,95,404,95,426,94,442,94,461,95,474,97,492,101,502,107,512,115,526,96,517,78,505,67,490,58,466,52,433,51,404,51,376,51,353,51" />
                <area id = "t3R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="87,144,85,127,105,112,120,104,141,98,162,93,190,91,211,90,238,92,266,92,286,94,317,96,331,95,342,94,343,138,316,140,282,139,250,136,220,133,189,132,162,131,139,132,113,136" />
                <area id = "t3L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,95,342,139,365,138,390,136,416,135,440,134,460,132,480,131,500,135,516,142,516,124,509,114,491,102,467,96,430,95,394,96,362,95" />
                <area id = "t4R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,139,341,190,321,190,295,192,268,192,244,192,221,191,184,190,170,188,153,187,136,184,110,179,98,174,88,171,85,145,100,139,120,134,140,132,160,130,182,132,206,133,237,135,256,137,275,139,296,140,318,140"/>
                <area id = "t4L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,139,342,190,364,192,396,194,417,192,445,190,466,183,481,179,496,174,505,168,515,162,515,140,498,134,473,131,448,134,420,136,393,136,368,139,349,139" />
                <area id = "t5R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,191,342,239,326,237,312,235,285,237,261,240,234,239,210,239,189,237,169,236,149,233,129,229,113,225,100,219,90,213,88,171,98,176,110,181,129,185,149,188,172,191,196,192,218,192,237,193,262,193,287,193,314,192,325,192" />
                <area id = "t5L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,191,342,239,364,241,393,240,417,240,443,235,465,231,480,226,494,220,504,216,512,208,514,207,513,163,504,170,487,179,465,185,439,192,417,193,400,195,364,193" />
                <area id = "t6R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,239,342,280,318,283,294,283,272,283,252,280,226,280,205,278,182,276,161,273,146,267,132,261,117,254,105,247,94,240,93,213,110,223,128,230,152,233,172,235,197,236,229,239,254,239,281,238,304,235,317,235,331,238" />
                <area id = "t6L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,239,343,283,368,282,392,281,416,279,436,275,455,268,472,261,486,253,496,248,505,240,512,236,515,208,501,217,486,224,458,233,432,237,402,240,372,241,353,240" />
                <area id = "t7R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,283,343,336,322,336,288,333,262,332,231,328,209,323,190,320,172,315,152,310,136,305,120,299,108,289,102,287,96,240,108,249,125,259,144,267,166,274,188,279,211,280,242,282,269,283,294,284,317,284" />
                <area id = "t7L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,282,344,334,373,331,406,327,428,322,451,314,472,307,490,296,501,287,506,279,513,234,505,240,489,250,473,259,449,268,428,275,418,277,389,280,357,281" />
                <area id = "t8R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="341,335,342,374,319,375,298,377,276,377,248,373,224,368,204,362,179,355,158,348,140,342,128,336,117,330,105,288,116,295,128,303,143,307,162,312,181,318,200,322,224,326,249,331,273,332,298,334,325,335" />
                <area id = "t8L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="342,335,342,374,354,374,374,372,392,370,408,365,424,360,438,354,449,348,462,341,474,336,486,328,498,319,502,303,505,290,505,283,498,290,488,298,472,307,455,311,437,317,418,322,396,326,377,331" />
                <area id = "t9R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="336,374,337,424,329,423,320,419,310,420,299,422,286,423,277,423,261,418,246,412,234,403,217,394,201,388,185,382,169,378,156,374,140,368,131,362,122,358,117,329,125,334,133,339,146,344,158,348,175,354,188,358,204,363,218,366,232,370,251,374,265,375,282,376,296,376,314,376" />
                <area id = "t9L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="336,376,337,424,358,423,372,419,385,412,406,403,418,395,430,389,445,381,462,373,474,367,487,358,493,352,499,319,490,327,478,334,464,343,451,349,433,357,417,363,396,369,366,375,345,376" />
                <area id = "t10R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="330,424,331,482,310,482,296,481,274,477,254,469,238,460,227,449,206,435,195,427,177,417,164,412,150,405,138,398,128,393,122,359,132,365,148,372,162,377,178,383,195,389,212,395,228,401,244,411,260,418,272,423,287,424,303,423,315,420,324,422" />
                <area id = "t10L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="330,424,333,481,354,479,368,476,380,469,392,463,401,453,414,440,423,429,437,419,449,410,463,402,476,393,488,387,493,351,486,359,474,367,459,375,440,384,428,391,414,399,402,405,385,414,368,419,351,424" />
                <area id = "t11R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="316,481,317,545,298,546,279,544,264,540,250,533,235,525,221,511,212,498,200,480,188,467,173,454,160,444,146,437,134,429,125,420,127,391,141,401,157,409,177,417,193,426,212,439,233,456,246,467,265,473,282,479,301,482" />
                <area id = "t11L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="317,482,317,545,340,542,359,536,376,529,392,518,406,506,418,487,429,473,442,458,455,443,466,435,483,426,492,424,489,387,474,394,459,403,443,412,433,420,422,430,410,442,400,452,386,466,368,475,342,481" />
                <area id = "t12R" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="300,547,301,596,278,596,262,593,247,588,234,580,228,568,221,557,210,536,200,521,187,507,176,497,160,481,147,475,133,464,126,460,122,420,134,429,146,436,159,444,177,457,193,473,206,489,218,509,235,525,250,535,270,542" />
                <area id = "t12L" shape="poly"  href="#" coords="300,547,302,597,329,595,347,594,367,586,382,573,394,553,406,533,419,515,432,497,448,482,464,469,480,460,488,457,492,424,477,429,462,438,447,451,436,464,424,480,413,495,400,511,377,527,358,537,321,545" />
        </map>
    </body>
```